# Site not loading completely when external script fails

Tags: javascript, html, load, external

I have a script on my site from easypolls.net which is basically a voting poll but if for example their site is down, or there is a problem loading the script then the rest of the content on my site isn't loading.

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.easypolls.net/ext/scripts/emPoll.js?p=5075b1e0e4b08bb807c01061"></script><a class="OPP-powered-by" href="http://www.objectplanet.com/opinio/" style="text-decoration:none;"><div style="font: 9px arial; color: gray;"></div></a>
```

So how can I fix this, is it normal javascript issue? or am I doing something wrong?
The script is inside a div in the body section.

Comment: Where is this `script` tag referenced in the DOM?

Comment: Inside a div, in the body section.

Answer (score 1):

If you are currently referencing this script in the `HEAD` of your document, then you might try adding that script tag right before the closing `BODY` tag.

Comment: The script is placed where the poll is going to be displayed, which is in the body section. There were no further instructions about this on their website, you just copy paste the script.

Answer (score 1):

I would use js library such as [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) to make an asynchronous call to that js file with `errorTimeout` property set 2-4 sec? and if it cant be retrieved you can always notify user in corresponding callback functions. Display message, hide the poll? or what ever you want with js/jQuery or similar.

Answer (score 1):

There is some good information about this issue by [Steve Souders](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/)

Are you trying to load your site in IE? Because IE breaks sometimes when a script file doesn't load properly.

Also try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.easypolls.net/ext/scripts/emPoll.js?p=5075b1e0e4b08bb807c01061"></script>
```

Add a closing bracket to the end of the script. This is good practice, and might solve some problems

Comment: Is that javascript file integral to your site? (Can it function without it?)

Comment: If I understood your question then yes. This script is just for a poll. Problem is that when the external JS is not loading(e.g their server is down) everything below that script on my website is not loading because it waits for the poll script to load.

Comment: I don't know about easypolls. If it's possible to put that link at the bottom of the page, without breaking the script it could fix your problem. Test it and see what happens

Comment: No, if I put the script only(out of full code) on the bottom the poll is not working. Updated first post with full code.

Comment: When I put the javascript link into a jFiddle, it only allowed code below the link when I added ></script> to the end of it. Instead of >

Comment: Basically they don't want you to customize it. Here is the jFiddle try to run it couple of times if it doesn't load: http://jsfiddle.net/aFhYw/

Comment: Nope, not working. Basically when you remove the script above the link it gives an error...

Comment: Yeah, I signed up for an account and got a poll script from them. I messed with the code for a little while, and they have a pretty strong filter. I would recommend you use http://www.micropoll.com/ if you can. Comes with many more customizations. And its free.